# subprocess.Popen fails with The system cannot find the file specified for command "dir"

Tags: windows, python-2.7, subprocess

I am working in Python2.7 with subprocess.Popen inoder to perform nmake a c file task.

Platform: Windows 10

Python Version: 2.7

For testing, i am using "dir" command in the place of nmake to test subprocess.Popen works or not, as it fails in python script. Refer below code which i have executed in python prompt,

`

```
3 [D:\notes-capi\samples] "c:\Python27\python.exe"

Python 2.7.18 (v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 20 2020, 13:19:08) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['dir'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 644, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['dir'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 644, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I tried the same command using os.system("dir"), it works fine. Any suggestion on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Note: If someone feels it is redundant question. Please suggest the solution link as google didn't helped me on this.

Comment: `dir` is an internal command of the shell, so you need to use `shell=True`. Also do not pass a list of arguments with `shell=True`. Use `p = subprocess.Popen('dir', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`.

Comment: I tried the with subprocess.Popen('dir', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True). It failed again with same error

Comment: Edit your question to show exactly what you tried and the result.